# Toggle visibility of ToolStrip

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a toolstrip and a statusstrip and I toggle their Visible property.
The form is minimized to system tray when "closed".

```
    private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
        this.Hide();
    }
```

I close the application from ContextMenu of NotifyIcon and I want to save the visibility of toolstrip (statusstrip).
The problem is that they are always false when the form is "closed".
Is possible to distinguish when they are really not visible or the form is hidden

Comment: Your best bet would be to create a field, like `ToolstripsVisibleWhenShwon`, and set and clear that variable when the user indicates that strips should be shown/hidden.  It would then clearly represent the state that you are tracking.

Comment: The Visible property is a bit unusual, when you read it back then you get the actual state of the control.  Always *false* when you've hidden the window.  You'll just need to keep an extra variable around.  Or set the app setting when you assign the Visible property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't quite understand where the problem is and how you can't distinguish form state. 
Why not to compare FormWindowState enums and set component settings?

1 add application setting:

Name: Visible

Type: bool

Scope: User

Value: False

2 wherever in your code set component property.

```
if (this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
      {
         toolStrip.Visible = true;
      }
         else
      {
         toolStrip.Visible = false;
      }
```

3 finally save settings

```
using myApplication.Properties;
private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
     {
         Settings.Default.Visible = toolStrip.Visible ;
         Settings.Default.Save(); 
     }
```

Comment: I want to save toolstrip.Visible state. When form is closed (this.Hide()) toolstrip returns always false

Comment: then save it before this.hide(). hide() method sets visible property of control to false, that's how it works. in this case you hide form, not toolstrip. how to create, modify and save toolstrip setting is shown in code above.